# Using jQuery to check if div has text and a span of a certain class

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
<div class="testDivClass">
    Some text!
    <div>
        <span class="testSpanClass">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to return true or an object that's not null (basically a boolean to test) - which tells me that this div (of class testDivClass) does contains 'Some text!' and does have a span of class "testSpanClass" (which, please note, is not a direct child of the 'root' div).

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

So far I have:

```
$("div.testDivClass:contains('Some text!')");
```

which is fine, but I don't know where to go from here. Using `.children(".testSpanClass")` gives me nothing.

EDIT: I've tried .has() - that too returns nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.testDivClass').is(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf("Some text!") > -1 && $(this).find("span.testSpanClass").length
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2KVp/

With selector:

```
$('.testDivClass').is(':contains("Some text!"):has(span.testSpanClass)');
```

Selector demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2KVp/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot Esailija!! I'll give this a whirl. At first glance, a lot more complex than what I expected to be honest. Thanks again +1.

Comment: With selector it would be something like `is( ':contains("Some text!"):has(span.testSpanClass)')` It works as well: see http://jsfiddle.net/Y2KVp/2/

Comment: The function version is somewhat faster if that's important (it shouldn't be :P) http://jsperf.com/selectorfunctionistest

Comment: Esailija thanks a lot for this, I'll mark as answer when it allows me to. Can I just ask - what if I were to extend this and say that instead of span.testSpanClass - I want to check if it has a span who's name contains "SpanText123" and is set to Display:none; in the style?

Comment: @DeeMac `.is(':contains("Some text!"):has(span[name*="SpanText123"]:hidden)');`

Comment: Thanks again, you don't realise how much time this has saved me.

Answer (score 1):

I've create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcpH2/5/) to demonstrate how to do it...

```
!!$("div.testDivClass:contains('Some text!')").find(".testSpanClass").length;
```

The two exclamation marks convert 0 into false and any other number into true.